# Data studio filter - some of String data converting to date range automatically

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio, data-studio-custom-visuals

In my data studio dashboard i have team size filter. This team size column contains(in google sheets) few types of team sizes(0-1,2-5,501-1000 ... ).  My problem is when i add a filter using this team size column it shows date ranges(some of data). 2-5 team size shows as 2020-02-05 likewise. Data type for team size is string in data studio.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue Identification

Was able to replicate the issue. Currently it seems that the values `2-5` and `6-10` were automatically detected as Date values in Google Sheets (notice that Dates are right aligned as opposed to Plain Text values which are left aligned in Google Sheets).

### Suggestion

In Google Sheets, select the column and set the format to `Plain Text` and refresh the Google Data Studio Report to view the refreshed data showing the values as expected.

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/579620d9-bd18-4b18-af11-28692f696adf) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]